# Centering div inside another div and on image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a one page website. The idea is to have a div for each image (using bootstrap). This will create the back ground image for the div. Then I want to place another div on where I can place text and other images in. I managed to get it to work using the position from the top but I want to use dimensions relative to the divs so that when it is displayed on a smaller screen the content in the center div is still center and set to the appropriate size.

Here is the div:

```
<div class="row" id="homeRow">
    <img id="homeImage" src="imageSource" alt="Example">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" id="homeTitle">
        <img src="headingSource" alt="Handwriting Fonts">
        <h3>Some content</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are three of these in on the page. My css at the moment looks like this:

```
#homeRow{
height: 800px;
width: 100%;
color: white;
overflow:hidden;
}

#homeImage{
width: 100%;
position: relative;
-webkit-filter:brightness(60%);
-moz-filter:brightness(60%);
filter: url(#brightness);
filter:brightness(60%);
}

#homeTitle{
position: absolute;
top: 300px;
width: 50%;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

So I am looking for a solution that where I will be able to position everything inside of the row div relative to the row div.

Comment: try adding `position: relative;` to `#homeRow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#homerow{
    ...
    position: relative; // add this
}
#homeTitle{
    ...
    //width:50% - remove this
    left:25%; // add this
    right:25%; // add this
    // those left and right will make width 50% and centered
}
```

Example: https://jsbin.com/savaqoputo/edit?html,output

Answer (score 2):

```
#homeRow{
height: 800px;
width: 100%;
color: white;
overflow:hidden;
position: relative;
}

#homeImage{
width: 100%;
position: relative;
-webkit-filter:brightness(60%);
-moz-filter:brightness(60%);
filter: url(#brightness);
filter:brightness(60%);
}

#homeTitle{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
width: 50%;
left: 50%;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

Try using this CSS. You can use position relative for outer div and for inside position absolute.